# RenderTargetBitmap causes Insufficient Memory

Tags: c#, wpf, memory, rendertargetbitmap

I have seen threads going around before with this problem, but I can't seem to find a solution to my issue. I have an application that allows the user to create their own canvases. Let's say that in this example, the user creates 150 canvases that are 745px x 1045px. Now there is a functionality that allows the user to export these all into separate PNG files. Here is my method that does that:

```
public static void ExportToPng(Uri path, Canvas surface)
{
    if (path == null) return;

    Size size = new Size(surface.Width, surface.Height);
    surface.Measure(size);
    surface.Arrange(new Rect(size));
    surface.UpdateLayout();

    RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap =
      new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)size.Width,
        (int)size.Height,
        96d,
        96d,
        PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    renderBitmap.Render(surface);

    using (FileStream outStream = new FileStream(path.LocalPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));
        encoder.Save(outStream);
    }
}
```

After about 45 images or so, the application breaks on the line: *renderBitmap.Render(surface);* saying:
**Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.**

Now I understand that this process can be a bit of a memory hog, but I feel like after an image is rendered and exported as a PNG, I should be able to dispose of it somehow before moving on to the next image. I'm just not sure how to do that. Any and all advice is appreciated!

Comment: RenderTargetBitmap class always does this. I suggest a different approach.

Comment: I am up to the task of using a different approach, however, I do not know of others. Any help there as well would also be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: before that, can you try `renderBitmap.Clear()` at the end of ExportToPng method

Comment: well I found this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/18e3404b-fb0c-4861-b497-f0d40bed675a/rendertargetbitmap-memory-leak?forum=wpf#2d4e2ba5-f194-46ff-8b79-fe83e0759624) I hope it works.

Comment: Same issue, except that it broke on the initialization of renderBitmap instead of the Render method itself this time.

Comment: That link looks promising. I will try it out!

Comment: You should dispose(Or clear) bitmap. This happend because c# doesnt delete used bitmap from memory and you should delete it manualy

Comment: @jackjop I implemented that solution, but it still broke on the render after about 45 images.

Comment: @Mikhail - I tried implementing both fixes that jackpop had suggested, but neither worked. Wouldn't either of those dispose of the bitmap?